# Python Keep running my imported scripts before subprocess call

Tags: python, import, subprocess, popen

Okay, `newserial.py` is the main script I execute, `trackid.py` is second script i want to execute through `subprocess.call("trackid.py",shell=True)`. I placed `__init__.py` in and all files in the same folder.

Problem: However, when I use: `import trackid`, it automatically executes the script before it reaches the line: `subprocess.call("trackid.py",shell=True)`.
I read tutorial saying you should place in my code:

```
def main():
  if__name__=="__main__" 
  ...
```

Yet, it doesn't help! I put `def main():` in both scripts `newserial.py` and `trackid.py`

**Questions:**
How do I stop this from happening?
How do I execute `trackid.py` as a subprocess and automatically end the script and continue with the remaining line of the main script `newserial.py`?
How do I prevent functions with the same name from clashing when I import?
What is the best when to use s`ubprocess.call`/ `subprocess.Popen` what are all the pipes for?

Answer (score 0):

What is meant by the hint that you've found already is that you should wrap all your code in trackid.py like this:

```
def mytrackid():
    all your code goes here
    bla print bla

if __name__ == '__main__':
    mytrackid()
```

All the code that is *not* within a function or class will be executed at the moment that a module is imported.
With

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
```

you make sure that this part is only being executed when the module is actually the main module.

Comment: Like i wrote they are both in a function def main(). trackid.py is not the main file newserial.py is the main file. i combined both codes together. The def main() houses the main code(newserial.py) and inside it lies def def dmain() endind with line if __name__ == '__main__':, Yet I get an error: unboundlocalerror:local variable 'dmain' referenced before assignment. I am using a function not a variable. How do I make my functions global so they can be accessed within the same script? I must confess python seems to be unstructured. For simple task like this. I am not building a nuclear warhead!

Comment: just like you said 2nd script was supposed to run the first script. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you are only calling `trackid.py` via `subprocess.call()`, then you don't need to import it at all.

You import a module only if it contains functions that you wish to call in your script that is doing the importing, so

**script1.py**:

```
def myfun():
   do stuff

def myfun2():
   return(results)
```

**script2.py**:

```
import script1

script1.myfun()
print script1.myfun2()
```

When you import a module any code that is not in a function will be executed, hence the problem you are seeing. The `if __name__ == __main__` construct is used, normally, to add code that is run for testing purposes when the script is running standalone.

In this case, putting your code from `trackid.py` in the `if __name__...` block will ensure it is only executed when you do your `subprocess.call()` and not when you import the module but, I'm not sure why you want to do this; the [subprocess](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html) module is generally used to execute *non-python* code.

I think what you probably want to do is have `trackid.py` like my `script1`, above where it contains function(s) which you can call from `newserial.py` after importing it.

Comment: Like I wrote they are both in a function def main(). Kindly re-read my post. I don't want the script to run when i import it, I just want it to be executed when it reaches the subprocess. newserial.py is the main script trackid.py is the second script. Even after removing the import line and if__name_ . The track.py script takes over my program by running first. i thought python was a scripting language line by line. why then does it jump to subprocess line. How can i import a variable from trackid.py so it can be used in my main serial.py? How can I make a function global?

Comment: You are not being clear. Maybe if you posted some actual code above, it would help. If your code is in a `If __name__== __main__` block, **it will not run** when the code is imported. Please have a look at how to write a [mcve]

Comment: Thanks, I figured it out and now the 2nd script was supposed to call the first script. okay now i see...

Comment: If my answer has helped, please consider marking as correct or up-voting.